# Swift IOS Issues updating Label in DetailView from MasterView

Tags: ios, swift

My first posting on stackoverflow, so sorry if its not right

I am using the Master/Detail View template in XCode. This is a BLT Central app and it gets notified of events happening on the BLE device.
I have a Master view, this is updated using

```
    public  func    UpdateView() {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

This works fine and the TableView shows the updates live whenever the BLE notifies

However I also want to update the detail view live, incase this is being shown.

I have the label linked in the DetailView via:

```
@IBOutlet   weak var detailDescription: UILabel!
```

And it updates just fine when the MasterView seques to the DetailView

However if I try to update the Label when the BLE notify arrives the @IBOutlet detailDescription has turned to nil, so the update fails (Label not linked)

```
func UpdateDetail() {
    guard let label = detailDescription else {
        return; //Label not linked
    }
    label.text = "New Data"
}
```

The UpdateDetail() function is also used in viewDidLoad() and in that case its working fine

Whats really weird is that if I add a timer in the DetailView to just do the update

```
    var timer : Timer? = nil

@objc func fireTimer() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.UpdateDetail()
    }
}
```

It works fine, so its possibly something to do with calling the UpdateDetail() function from outside the Detail class.

I have checked if the detailDescription reference gets reset by adding a didSet to the property, and its only called once when the view is loaded

Guess I could use the timer work around, but I am totally baffled why the detailItem appears as nil sometimes, so would be grateful for a sanity check.

UPDATE Gone back to basics_______

So I have now gone back to the standard Apple Master->Detail view template and added a simple timer which updates the list. The ListView updates fine, however it still does not update the detail view dynamically.  outside its own class.

I am using on a 1 second timer after MainView is loaded, the list view updates fine, however the detail does not.

When debugging it steps into configureView() fine, but detailDescriptionLabel is nil after the first viewDidLoad()

Have tried all the suggestions below, however in each case the weak reference to the label is nil after the initial Load

Totally baffled

```
    @objc func doTimer() {
    for index  in 0..<objects.count {
        objects[index]=(objects[index] as! NSDate).addingTimeInterval(1)
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.detailViewController?.configureView()
    }
}
```

Full code for MasterViewController.swift here, rest is the same as standard template.

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var objects = [Any]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(insertNewObject(_:)))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    if let split = splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
//Added timer here
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(doTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

//Update data in list
@objc func doTimer() {
    for index  in 0..<objects.count {
        objects[index]=(objects[index] as! NSDate).addingTimeInterval(1)
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.detailViewController?.configureView()
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = splitViewController!.isCollapsed
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

@objc
func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any) {
    objects.insert(NSDate(), at: 0)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}

// MARK: - Segues

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Table View

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.description
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you call the `UpdateDetail` method in the non-timer version? Is it called on UI thread?

Comment: Yes, I added
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.detailViewController?.UpdateDetail()
        }

Comment: Hello there and welcome on board. Do you have a link to the project?

Comment: https://github.com/RLTeachGit/DetailViewIssue.git
I have uploaded it here

Comment: Unrelated but `begin-/endUpdates()` has no effect at all when `reload`ing rows or data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on the provided Git repository.

In MasterViewController - you are calling `self.detailViewController?.configureView()` but you never assign the detail controller and because it's `nil` it fails to call the `configureView` function. You can do that in `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` by setting `self.detailViewController = controller`

This won't still help you with the update of the label value.

The reason fo that is because in `@objc func doTimer() {` you are always setting (overriding) a new `Date` object into your array (what you probably aimed for is to update value for same reference). Because of this, the reference you assigned to detailViewController is different and you never update the `detailItem` in your timer. Hence calling the `configureView` won't make any change as the value remained the same.

Comment: Many thanks for taking a look at this
I thought this too, however after the first seque the value is set and the configureview() is called, I checked this by setting a BP and tracing into the call. The trace confirms it calls configureview() however once inside
  @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
is nil
I also added code to resync detailItem just before the call and it still does not update.

Many thanks for all your help, but I think its taken enough time and I don't have to do it this way, it was just my first attempt at Swift so needed a sanity check

Comment: Here is your project with my correction - perhaps it might explain some things https://transfernow.net/25fc20z8ac06

Comment: OK, that works A-OK. Thank you!
So is this the magic line? self.detailViewController?.detailItem = self.objects[0]

Comment: That was so incredibly helpful, thank you for taking the time. I have accepted your answer, but don't have the rep your to to more good.

Comment: BTW. I appears that underlying issue is that detailViewController which set up in viewDidLoad() is not the same instance as the one in the seque let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController, so setting anything using detailViewController does not impact the actual currently displayed detailview. When I use the one set in the seque it works just fine, and your example led me straight to this conclusion.

Answer (score -2):

It's happening because your detailDescription label is weak "weak var detailDescription". and each time you write this code

```
guard let label = detailDescription else {
        return; //Label not linked
    }
    label.text = "New Data"
```

you create a new object and assign value to that object. So the original value for detailDescription label object doesn't change. Try using the same detailDescription object everytime when you change its value.

Comment: `UILabel` is a `class` which is passed by reference and therefore the statement above only assigns the reference to `label` (as long as unwrapping succeeds); hence your statement is invalid